# Laravel Auth Routes

Tags: laravel

I have created a new Laravel application and ran `make:auth` for default authentication scaffolding. I am using `ngrok` for accessing my application from outside world. The issue is all form posting and routes are using my server name instead of application URL for example, registration form posts to

```
<servername>/register
```

instead of

```
<APP_URL>/register
```

any help in fixing this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of research i found out that i have to include following line in my `web.php`

```
\URL::forceRootUrl(env('APP_URL'));
```

now all my routes uses `APP_URL` value from `.env` file.

Hope this helps someone in future...